# How do symbols work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Node.JS v0.11.3 claims to have support for ECMAScript 6 symbols with the `--harmony_symbols` flag (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-dev/DE1syUbbDw8)). The latest draft [says](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.1.6)

> Properties are identified using key values. A key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value.

I have tried the following example

```
var mySymbol = new Symbol('Test symbol');
console.log(mySymbol.name); // prints 'Test symbol', as expected

var a = {};
a[mySymbol] = 'Hello!';
```

but I get an error on the last line

> TypeError: Conversion from symbol to string

How do symbols work? Is my example wrong, or does Node.JS actually *not* support symbols?

Comment: I cannot even find the `Symbol` constructor in the latest draft.

Comment: That only describes the data *type*. For example, further above you will see `The Null Type`. There is no `Null` constructor function either.

Comment: @Randomblue: That's just the description of a `Symbol` type. There's no specification of a `Symbol()` constructor to create them, like you used it. The draft is not yet finished :-)

Comment: For reference, stuff that's not supported at all usually fails with a much less specific error message.  The fact that the error even mentions symbols is a very strong hint that they're supported (at least to some degree; how well, i haven't a clue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try without `new`:

```
var mySymbol = Symbol('Test symbol');
console.log(mySymbol.name); // prints 'Test symbol', as expected

var a = {};
a[mySymbol] = 'Hello!';
```